# ajax with select tag rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using rails 4 to make an app like craigslist. I have a list of items on my index page. I am trying to create a dropdown select with options 'price', 'Most recent' so that users can sort the items based on these. Now, i need to send an ajax request to my '/items' url with params 'price' or 'most recent'. I have tried a lot of things but none have worked so far and i am completely stuck. This is the latest code i have. Are there any UBJ parameters i can use to accomplish this? I am new to rails and especially ajax, any help would be appreciated? Thanks in advance.

```
<script>
     $('#sort_by').on('change',function()
     {
         $.ajax({ type: "GET",
           url: "/items",
           data: {sort: $(this).val();},
           return false
         })
     }
</script>
```

Comment: <%= select_tag('sort_by', options_for_select([["Price- Lowest To Highest",1],["Price- Highest To Lowest",2],["MostRecent",3]])) %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#sort_by').on('change', function(){
  $.ajax({ type: "GET",
     url: "/items",
     data: { sort: $('option:selected', this).val() }
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: That worked, i was able to send the request with sort =2 parameter. However, i am not able to get the javascript response back. I already added 'respond_to :html, :js' to my controller and also created a index.js.erb file containing '$("#allitems").html("<%= escape_javascript(render @items) %>")'

Comment: When i send the ajax request, its still rendering the page in format.html instead of the index.js.erb page. It should be looking for a javascript response right? I am not sure why its not rendering the contents of index.js.erb file.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#sort_by').on('change', function(){
    $.ajax({ type: "GET",
        url: "/items",
        data: { sort: $('option:selected', this).val() },
        dataType : "script"
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: This code finally worked, was able to render the index.js.erb after sending this request using dataType : "script" option.